# What is the difference between 가게 됐어요, 가게 돼요 and 게 될 거예요?

Tags: grammar, meaning, phrase-meaning

i have 3 sentences as follows:

> 1. 흐엉 씨는 한국으로 가게 됐어요
> 2. 흐엉 씨는 한국으로 가게 돼요
> 3. 흐엉 씨는 한국으로 가게 될 거예요.

How are the 3 sentences above different? I understand the "게 되다" structure, but still don't understand the difference between 가게 됐어요, 가게 돼요 and 가게 될 거예요.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base form -게 되다 signifies coming to a certain state or ending up doing something, without saying the exact reason or course of events that led to it.

가게 됐어요 means the decision has been made for the person to go (either by themselves or by others).  So it means they did not go yet, but they will in due time.  -ㅆ어요 here describes a completed state, where the completion is that of deciding rather than actually going.

가게 될 거예요 means the decision for them to go has not yet been made, but the speaker thinks it will.  This phrase is roughly equivalent to "will (probably) be V-ing" in English, which is about expected or scheduled future. Saying -게 될 거예요 instead of the simpler -ㄹ 거예요 is so as to clarify that it may or may not be the person's own choice.

가게 돼요 is used much less than the other two.  It can loosely mean either of the two phrases (it's not as clear though, so not recommended).  It can also be a statement in telling a story, since the past is often told in the present tense (to make it more compelling) in novels and other types of stories.

Examples:

- 저는 부산으로 전근 가게 됐어요 = It has been decided for me to transfer to Busan.
- 저는 부산으로 전근 가게 될 거예요 = It looks like I'll end up transferring to Busan.
- 임꺽정은 고향을 떠나 전국을 방랑하게 된다 = 임꺽정 (fictional character) leaves his home and ends up traveling all over the country.